# Kendo mobile: Can I implement a stretched view with browser native scroll

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I want to use kendo-mobile widgets (application, view navigation) but a little in a different way it is documented and demonstrated.

I would like to define all application views with attribute stretch = true

```
<div data-role="view" data-stretch="true">
```

but with possibility to use browser native scroll (not kendo scroll) if content is bigger than viewport size.

By default if I set stretch=true on view element it is stretched to occupy whole viewport but if it is bigger then screen size the content is trimmed and user cannot see (scroll down) the rest of the document.

Is it possible to do this without interfering a lot in kendo lib files (js, css)?
I would like to avoid using kendo built-in scroller because it doesn't work well on "old" tablets with e.g. android ver. 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native overflow scrolling for elements in Android 2.2. You can try using the Kendo UI Mobile application level native scrolling setting, if you're willing to forfeit some of the framework features. More info in [our documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/mobile/native-scrolling).